# Kronecker structured matrix inversion

Tags: matrices, inverse, kronecker-product

suppose a blocked matrix that can be expressed via several kronecker products:
$
Z =\begin{pmatrix}
A \otimes B & C\otimes D \\
E\otimes F & G\otimes H 
\end{pmatrix}
$

where $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$ are matrices.
Is there an easy way to invert the matrix Z? I have tried several ansatzs, but they all fail. E.g. via the Woodbury matrix identity. However, then one has to invert $ A \otimes B  - C\otimes D (G\otimes H)^{-1}  E\otimes F$ which isnt easy at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The decomposition of its maximally ranked upper echelon matrix is through a filter then the determinate of the higher ranked entries is valid. You then multiply the fields character array by its norm array (adjacency constraints) and divide it by this determinant. That is to say for a rank k upper echelon matrix, of n x n dimensions, and a n x n character array with a p number of Prime factors will have  n - k mod (p) inverses. When i say Prime i mean character factors that are compact and surjective.

Comment: So I have thought about that quite a long time now. But I do not get what the algorithm should look like. So first of all I should run Gaussian elimination? But then I could invert it, however, then you cannot use the structure of the matrix. What exactly is the fields character array?